# sql query to average energy every 15 minutes

Tags: mysql

Options (my table)

```
id      datetime           energy   
1   2014-10-28 04:00:00     14     
1   2014-10-28 04:05:00     16
1   2014-10-28 04:10:00     23
1   2014-10-28 04:15:00     45
1   2014-10-29 04:00:00     34
1   2014-10-29 04:05:00     33
1   2014-10-29 04:10:00     12
1   2014-10-29 04:15:00     67
```

output

```
id    datetime 
1     2014-10-28 04:15:00    28
1     2014-10-29 04:15:00    37.33
```

my query:

```
SELECT date(`datetime`) dateDay,id, 
15*floor(date_format(`datetime`,'%i')/15) dateHour, 
avg(energy) FROM `meter` 
WHERE `datetime` >= '2014-10-28 00:00:01' AND `datetime` <= '2014-10-29 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY id,day(datetime),month(datetime),dateHour
```

Comment: Could you build your example in sql fiddle ? That would make it a lot clearer. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: You know 04:00:00 to 04:15:00 have 15*60+1 seconds, you cannot put them both in a 15 minutes period.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand, you want to achieve a grouping by 15 minutes intervals. If so, you would get along with something like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    avg(energy) as average_value,
    date_format(datetime, "%Y-m-d") as date_day,
    date_format(datetime,'%H') as date_hour
    IF(date_format(datetime,'%i') < 15, 0,
    IF(date_format(datetime,'%i') <= 30, 15,
    IF(date_format(datetime,'%i') <= 45, 30,45))) as fifteen_minutes_slot
from deliverydestination
GROUP BY id, date_day, date_hour, fifteen_minutes_slot
```

1) compute the fifteen_minutes slots with a set of ifs: if the value for minutes is less than 15, give it the value 0, else if it is less than 30, give it the value 15, etc...

2) group by day, hour and 15 minutes slot value. And by id, as in your example, if needed.

It would be nice to have a fiddle with your data, to show the final result...

Comment: Your approach will get the same result as OP does. And OP's approach is much clear an simple.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3004/9

Comment: Hum... That's true. the "15*floor(date_format(`datetime`,'%i')/15)" does the job pretty well. So what's the question ?

Comment: @Jaugar Chang BTW: the "15 minutes slot" is missing in the "output". That would help read the query. Thanks for the fiddle.